# Firebase join using Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to do join operation for data using the unique key provided by the Firebase database.Table habitat is created under the unique key of snake table.And also need to retrive data for list view or recyclerview.

```
databaseSnake = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("snake")
    .orderByKey()
    .addValueEventListener(
            new ValueEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {

                        // HERE CORRESPONDS TO JOIN
                        DatabaseReference Databasesnake = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                                .child("habitat")
                                .orderByKey()
                                .addValueEventListener(
                                        new ValueEventListener()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void     onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                            {
                                                // repeat!!
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                                            {

                                            }
                                        }

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                {

                }
```

[image: Structure of Database]

Comment: You need to be more clear in your question. What are the methods you tried ?

Comment: Plesase try to explain more clear what you want to do and what is the expected restult. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: I have two questions.1 code for the join operation is correct or not ?  2 how to retrive that data to list view? @AlexMamo